# 'ImproperlyConfigured at /admin/filebrowser/browse/ Error finding Upload-Folder (site.storage.location + site.directory).(Django File Browser) '

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-file-upload, django-filebrowser

My project structure is

```
main
 -temp
project
 -settings.py
```

I want to browse main/temp/ folder while navigating to the link: `localhost:8000/admin/filebrowser/browse`

Please help me with the correct settings of the django file browser, since the settings are not clear in the official documentation.
https://django-filebrowser.readthedocs.io/en/3.13.2/settings.html#settings

in settings.py

```
 FILEBROWSER_DIRECTORY = 'main/temp/'
```

Also tried:

```
from filebrowser.sites import site
site.directory = "main/temp/"
```

The error traceback is :

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/filebrowser/browse/

Django Version: 3.1.5
Python Version: 3.8.5
Installed Applications:
['grappelli',
 'filebrowser',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'main',
 'userapp']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'FedMall.privatemiddleware.NeedToLoginMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\filebrowser\decorators.py", line 36, in decorator
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(_("Error finding Upload-Folder (site.storage.location + site.directory). Maybe it does not exist?"))

Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured at /admin/filebrowser/browse/
Exception Value: Error finding Upload-Folder (site.storage.location + site.directory). Maybe it does not exist?
```

Comment: Please add complete error traceback to the question, also your (relevant) settings

Comment: edited settings the error is written in the question

Comment: That was half of the task.

Comment: So, I was asking for the proper settings file that navigates to the particular directory, urls and other things are correct.

Comment: error traceback is also included @JPG